# Set window size beyond screen resolution in Qt

Tags: macos, qt, user-interface, window

I want to set a `QT window` size beyond my screen size (i.e. 10 000px) but when I use

```
resize(10000, 800);
```

the window auto-fit to my screen max res (1280*800) and I have no idea how to over-pass this.
I'm using `QT` on `Mac Os X`.

Comment: I have a feeling that this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: You're might be right. I want a window larger than my screen, maybe resize() is not the best way to do it

Comment: But _why_ you need a window larger than the screen? Do you want to hide something from the user? Or do you want to show something big?

Comment: I want to display a very large strip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your images (or other widgets) inside a [QScrollArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html).

Comment: Is this the only viable solution?

Comment: It's the only solution that _I_ know. And it is so good a solution that haven't ever had to try to find any other solutions. You can't make windows larger that the screen, and from usability viewpoint that is a very good restriction. If your content is larger than the screen, you need to scroll. QScrollArea provides you that facility. If you have some other requirements, you should tell those requirements in your question.